# how to specify multiple log files pattern in fail2ban jail?

Tags: fail2ban

> I have log files on my server as follows

```
vpn_20191007.log
vpn_20191008.log
vpn_20191009.log
vpn_20191010.log
vpn_20191011.log
vpn_20191012.log
vpn_20191013.log
vpn_20191014.log
vpn_20191015.log
vpn_20191016.log
```

> Is it possible to add log files pattern in fail2ban jail config?

```
    [application]
    enabled  = false
    filter   = example
    action   = iptables
    logpath  = /var/log/vpn_%D.log
    maxretry = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, conditionally it is possible...

Although wildcards are basically allowed at the moment, so :

```
logpath  = /var/log/vpn_*.log
```

will do the job, but it is a bit ugly in your case:

- fail2ban cumulate the list of files only by start of service, so the list remains obtained in fail2ban (unless it gets reloaded) - this means you should notify fail2ban that the log file name got changed (see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1379, the work is in progress).
- since only one file will get new messages, the monitoring of other files is unneeded, especially if polling backend is used.

So better create some `logrotate` rules for that:

- in order to rename/compress all previous log-files (to avoid match for obsolete files);
- either create hard- or sym-link for last/active file with a fixed name (so fail2ban is always able to find it with the same name, and you'd not need wildcard at all);
- or to notify fail2ban to reload the jail if logfile-name got changed
  (`fail2ban-client reload vpn`).

Here is an example for logrotate amendment:

```
    postrotate
        nfn="/var/log/vpn_$(date +%Y%m%d).log"
        touch "$nfn"
        ln -fs "$nfn" /var/log/vpn.log
```

Comment: yes. logrotate is the solution here but I can't symlink a file that changes every day. log files are created daily with date suffix.and also using wildcard is ugly because log files are of size 500MB approx.

Comment: of course you can link the log-file, just add something like this to your logrorate config for vpn service: 

    postrotate
        nfn="/var/log/vpn_$(date +%Y%m%d).log"
        touch "$nfn"
        ln -fs "$nfn" /var/log/vpn.log

and force logrotate execution daily on 00:00 (e.g. via cron);
the only logpath you'd monitor in fail2ban would be then "/var/log/vpn.log"

Comment: comments seems to be formated incorrectly, so I extended answer above with an example

Answer (score 2):

You can add wilcard :

```
logpath  = /var/log/vpn_*.log
```

and/or you can use multiple lines :

```
logpath  = /var/log/vpn_20191007.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191008.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191009.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191010.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191011.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191012.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191013.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191014.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191015.log
           /var/log/vpn_20191016.log
```

(You can combine the two)