# Custom fail2ban ban rule not working (incorrect failregex usage?)

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am currently trying to secure our backup server and it's interface as it currently does not have any kind of (extra) security other than a strong password. The backup server is based on CentOS 7.x.

Log file location:

```
/var/log/backup
```

Log file names:

```
backuplog-2019310.log
backuplog-2019309.log
backuplog-2019308.log
backuplog-2019307.log
```

False logins are logged like:

```
[2019-11-06T13:13:33+01:00] [Audit] Web login failure for account 'admin': Invalid authentication (Address=200.100.150.50:28534)
[2019-11-06T13:13:34+01:00] [Audit] Web login failure for account 'test': Invalid authentication (Address=120.30.40.20:28534)
[2019-11-06T13:13:35+01:00] [Audit] Web login failure for account 'info': Invalid authentication (Address=85.80.75.70:28534)
[2019-11-06T13:13:35+01:00] [Audit] Web login failure for account 'user': Invalid authentication (Address=25.125.155.190:28534)
```

In /etc/fail2ban/jail.local:

```
[backup]
enabled  = true
filter   = backup
logpath  = /var/log/backup/backuplog-*.log
port     = 80,443
```

The use of the asterisk in there is allowed, right?

So far I understand it correctly, I hope.

However I am experiencing issues with creating a correct filter for this custom fail2ban ban rule (= filter).

Example of /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/backup.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = [[]Web login failure for account []] .* Invalid authentication
ignoreregex =
```

But it's not working. So I am guessing my failregex is incorrect? Maybe someone can advice me the correct failregex to apply to make it work?

I am receiving the following error messages when starting up fail2ban:

```
ERROR  NOK: ("No 'host' group in '[[]Web login failure for account []] .* Invalid authentication'",)
```

So I am guessing the failregex is incorrect?

### //update 1 - STILL ISSUES + ADDITIONAL QUESTION

Fooled around a bit more. This is the updated failregex:

```
failregex = [][] Web login failure for account .* <HOST>
```

Now I am not getting the "ERROR NOK" anymore, however it's still not working. This is the fail2ban log:

```
2019-11-06 14:44:39,111 fail2ban.filter         [20978]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for authentication: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
2019-11-06 14:44:41,706 fail2ban.filter         [20978]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for authentication: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
2019-11-06 14:44:42,082 fail2ban.filter         [20978]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for authentication: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
2019-11-06 14:44:42,623 fail2ban.filter         [20978]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for authentication: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Also, coming to think of it, I think using "/var/log/backup/backuplog-*.log" is not that great. Especially when more and more log files are created. Right?

Is there a way to target the current or latest log file e.g. backuplog-2019310.log?

Thanks in advance.

In the meantime I will fool around a bit more.

### //update 2 - MAIN ISSUE SOLVED!!

I guess I solved it by using the following failregex:

```
failregex = Invalid authentication \(Address=<HOST>
```

Will see if I can make it somewhat better obviously. But it's a great start for me.

So maybe someone can help me with the issue in regards to the log file as mentioned above. For easier reading I will ask it here again:

> Also, coming to think of it, I think using
>   "/var/log/backup/backuplog-*.log" is not that great. Especially when
>   more and more log files are created. Right?
>
> Is there a way to target the current or latest log file e.g.
>   backuplog-2019310.log?

Maybe someone has a solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As for regex, it is always better to use anchored RE's, so either at end:

```
failregex = Invalid authentication \(Address=<HOST>\)\s*$
```

or at begin:

```
failregex = ^\[\] \[Audit\] Web login failure for account '[^']+': Invalid authentication \(Address=<HOST>
```

And disable `usedns` for this jail if no hostnames in log are expected (or use `<ADDR>` instead of `<HOST>` if f2b >= v.0.10).

As for current (latest) log file, simply create a symlink in `postrotate` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58430149/7161854).